# Quadratic non-residues in elliptic divisibility sequences

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, elliptic-curves, quadratic-residues

Let $E: y^2 = x^3 + ax + b$ be an elliptic curve over $\mathbb{Q}$ with $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$. Recall that any rational point $P = (x,y)$ can be written uniquely as $P = (u/d^2, v/d^3)$ with $u,v,d \in \mathbb{Z}, d > 0, \gcd(u,d) = \gcd(v,d) = 1$. We write $d(P)$ for the number appearing in the denominator.

The sequence $d(nP)$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$ is the *elliptic divisibility sequence* associated to $P$. My question is about existence of quadratic non-residues in these sequences modulo all but finitely many primes $p$.

> Let $P$ be a point of infinite order. Does there exists a finite set of primes $S$ such that for all $p \notin S$, there is $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that
> $$\left( \frac{d(nP)}{p}\right) = -1 \quad ? \quad (*)$$

Remarks:

1. It is known that the sequence $d(nP)$ contains only finitely many squares, by Theorem 1.1 of

   Everest, Reynolds, Stevens - On the denominators of rational points on elliptic curves.

   In particular, for all but finitely
   many $n$, one finds that $d(nP)$ is a quadratic non-residue modulo half of all primes.
   I want to know that as one varies $n$ and takes all these primes together, one only
   excludes finitely many primes.
2. There is a slightly different definition of elliptic divisibility sequences
   in terms of division polynomials and recurrence sequences, which can differ
   from the above sequence by a sign and some small primes (this is the original
   definition of Ward). I'm  also interested in the analogous problem
   for such sequences.

Comment: Is this known for Lucas sequences?

Comment: Good question. I don't know.

Comment: Is it even known that the primes excluded have density zero?

Comment: @Stanley Yao Xiao up to some work reconciling the definition difference, I think so: combine the main result in Reductions of Points on Elliptic Curves by Akbary et al, with the main result in Character Sums with Division Polynomials by Shparlinski and Stange.

Comment: We already have some ideas how to prove this "density zero" result, so are really looking for a proof that there are only finitely many exceptions.

Comment: It appears that for a fixed $E$ and $P$, the primes for which there is no $n$ so that $\left(\frac{d(nP)}{p}\right) = -1$ can be reasonably large. I just looked at the example of $E : y^{2} = x^{3} - 2x$ and $P = (2,2)$, and found that there is no such $n$ for $p = 17$, $257$, $1009$, $1361$, $26881$, and $141041$.

Comment: Still, heuristically the number of such $p$ should be finite: each $p$ divides $d(n_pP)$ for some $n_p$, and then there's periodicity. $\left(\frac{d(nP)}{p}\right)=1$ for all $n<n_p$ occurs with chance $2^{n_p}$. So we can estimate an upper bound for the number of "bad" primes: $\sum_n \omega(d(nP))/2^n$, where $\omega(k)$ is the number of distinct primes dividing $k$. Since $d(nP)=O(e^{cn^2})$ for some $c$, and $\omega(k)=O(\log{k})$, this sum is finite.